# C++ program start on boot Ubuntu Server

Tags: linux

I am trying to start a *.cpp program on boot so I did the following but it did not do the trick and I know I can put a command in .bashrc but I am not always logged into it and I need it to be running even if I never logged in.

```
 sudo cp <compiled cpp filename> /etc/init.d/
 sudo chmod 744 <filename>
 sudo update-rc.d <filename> defaults
```

Why is this not working??

Comment: The language the program is written in is completely irrelevant to having it start when the server boots.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login

Comment: @Zac: Almost completely irrelevant.  It does have implications for `PATH`, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, `LD_PRELOAD`, and other environment variables.

Answer (score 5):

- Don't put a binary program into /etc/init.d - put it into /usr/sbin or /usr/local/sbin instead and put a script running it into /etc/init.d
- What is the output of the `update-rc.d` command?
- Last but not the least, why mode 744 instead of 755?

Comment: No need for anybody else to be able to run it other than me 700 is what I have it on right now, I'll try a bash script instead thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1):

With `crontab -e` add

```
@reboot /your/binary/executable
```

Here's the [`cron` reference](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto#Advanced_Crontab).

Cheers,

Comment: I like the trick and I was hoping that it would work, but it did not. I created two scripts one to do smbmount and then the other one will run the executable and then I rebooted the machine and nothing happened

Comment: Using `@reboot` works! Are you sure it's not a env og path problem? Have you looked at logs? Permissions? As root or non-root?